# Ubuntu 14.10 + AMD 6550m

Tags: ati, xorg, fglrx

I got a HP DV6 3240 Notebook with a powerxpress video card, AMD HD 4200m + HD 6550m.
It works very well with Ubuntu 14.10 + open source xorg drivers.
But unfortunately i need some catalyst functions, i tried to install fglrx from "additional drivers" but after reboot and after i put my password on login screen i got stuck at wallpaper screen, tried also with fglrx-updates and got same result, stuck at wallpaper after login.
Tried several commands on ctlr+alt+f1 didn't help.
The only way i found i to use xorg drivers, who happens to run well.
Should i stick with xorg drivers or has any way to fix this with amd proprietary drivers ?
Thanks.